# dataframe using list vs dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

```py
import pandas as pd

pincodes = [800678,800456]
numbers = [2567890, 256757]
labels = ['R','M']
first = pd.DataFrame({'Number':numbers, 'Pincode':pincodes},
                     index=labels)
print(first)
```

The above code gives me the following (correct) dataframe.

```
    Number  Pincode
R  2567890   800678
M   256757   800456
```

But, when I use this statement,

```py
second = pd.DataFrame([numbers,pincodes],
                      index=labels, columns=['Number','Pincode'])
print(second)
```

then I get the following (incorrect) output.

```
    Number  Pincode
R  2567890   256757
M   800678   800456
```

As you can see, the two Data Frames are different. Why does this happen? What's so different in this dictionary vs list approach?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `pd.DataFrame()` includes this documentation.

```
Init signature: pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
Docstring:
...

Parameters
----------
data : ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame
    Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects

    .. versionchanged :: 0.23.0
       If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order for
       Python 3.6 and later.

    .. versionchanged :: 0.25.0
       If data is a list of dicts, column order follows insertion-order
       for Python 3.6 and later.
```

The key word is *column*. In the first approach, you correctly tell pandas that `numbers` is the column with label `'Numbers'`. But in the second approach, you tell pandas that the columns are `'Numbers'` and `'Pincode'` and to get the data from the list of lists `[numbers, pincodes]`. The first *column* of this list of lists is assigned to the `'Numbers'` column, and the second to the `'Pincode'` column.

If you want to enter your data this way (not as a dictionary), you need to transpose the list of lists.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

# old way
>>> pd.DataFrame([numbers,pincodes],
                 index=labels,columns=['Number','Pincode'])
    Number  Pincode
R  2567890   256757
M   800678   800456

# Transpose the data instead so the rows become the columns.
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([numbers,pincodes]),
                 index=labels,columns=['Number','Pincode'])
    Number  Pincode
R  2567890   800678
M   256757   800456
```